# confusing, seemingly unpractical Linux disk partitioning scheme

Tags: linux, partitioning, storage

Below is the output of `df -h` on our Redhat linux system.

```
$ df -h
/dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_root
                       50G   41G  5.9G  88% /
tmpfs                  12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   75M  378M  17% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_home
                      214G  189M  203G   1% /home
```

It was configured this way by our hosting provider and it is a dedicated server. We had already installed some important software and began using it for mission critical daily tasks before we realized the partition scheme ( which seems impractical to me, not sure why such a small partion dedicated to `/`?). Before contacting our hosting provider or lookng into other solutions I would like to consult the community here.

My main question is:

**Is there a way to "combine" `/dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_home` partition with the  `/dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_root` partition, WITHOUT wiping the `/dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_home` partition(which our `/home/` directory is mounted on).**

Also, of secondary importance, I would like to know if anyone could infer the reasoning behind this partitioning scheme, what is the need for the separate `/dev/sda1` - `/boot` partition? why would someone allocate such a small amount of space to `/`? Is `tmpfs` large enough? etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[  Reading your post, I suspect you may not be aware you are using Logical Volumes - this is a powerful mechanism for abstracting the disk from OS, and probably provides a solution to your problem as below ]

To answer your primary question - no, you can't merge to LVM partitions together.

That said, in this case you don't need to - you can get the desired end result without even rebooting the system!   You could simply copy  the data from /home to a new directory /home2, then unmount /home and rename /home2 to /home and remove the mapping from fstab.

Once you have done this you can destroy /dev/mapper/lv_d0-lv_home and reassign the space to /dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_root, and then expand the filesystem.

If you need specifics on how to do this, let me know - I  have not provided them because it does not answer the question you asked.

**With respect of the reasoning**

It is actually quite a logical partitioning scheme.

/boot needs to be on a physical disk because the BIOS does not know anything about logical volumes.  It thus needs a small disk it does know how to read, from which everything can be bootstrapped.  That disk is /dev/sda1, which is then mounted as /boot.

There is an assumption in this layout that you want to seperate data from programs - /dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_root contains the OS and programs, while /home is destined for the user data - While this assumption may not be what you want, its quire reasonable.

50 Gigs for the root file system is actually quite a lot, if you consider that a base Linux OS typically only takes 2 - 6 gigs - that leaves about 45 gigs for programs - again, it may not be what you want, but its a reasonable stab in the dark for an average system.

tmpfs is a special filesystem which is actually a RAM disk backed by swap space. It is way larger then it needs to be - if anything its to large - but, being that its backed by SWAP this is probably reasonable, and normally set by the OS.

**Additional Info - After Comments**

Please back up everything first.  There is always risk in doing hard drive resizes, moreso if you have not done it before.   I have not run these commands, so don't trust them blindly.

First off, A VERY basic primer on LVM -

LVM - Logical Volume Management - takes a disk (or 10), and divides them into 3 layers -

Physical Volumes - these are partitions set aside for use with LVM.  You can see a list of physical volumes with the command "pvs", or in depth info with "pvdisplay".

Volume Groups (VGs) - These are groups of physical volumes.  You can have 1 or more PV's in a VG, but a maximum of 1 VG per per PV.  It is typical to have a single VG - although if you have a mix of, for example SSD's and Hard drives, you may want to have the SSD's in 1 group and the hard drives in another.  You can see a summary of Volume Groups with the command "vgs" or details with "vgdisplay"

Logical Volumes (LV) sit on Volume groups - Again, you would have many logical volumes to 1 volume group.  You can see a summary of Logical volumes with the command "lvs" or the details with "lvdisplay".

Looking at /dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_root - your volume group will be "vg_d0" and your logical volume will be called "lv_root".

I'm uncomfortable suggesting you move /var as you are a lot more likely to break things - particularly if a program is trying to read from /var.

Here are the steps to grow your root partition -

- Freeing up the disk space by moving your /home directory:

LOG IN AS ROOT.  (You may have difficulty unmounting the system if
you are logged in as a regular user as regular users home directories
are under /home, while roots is /root.  If you can't log in as root,
make a temporary user, change there directory to /tmp and add them to
the "wheel" group).  Log in as them and then become root, then -

```
mkdir /home2
cp -var /home/* /home2
umount /home
mv /home2 /home
```

Edit /etc/fstab and comment out the line mounting /home.

```
lvremove /dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_home
```

Will then remove the "lv_home" volume group, freeing it up for reuse.  You will need to confirm you wish to remove the volume.  Prior to executing this command you should satisfy yourself that eveything that was in /home still is.

You now have 203 gigs more space to reassign as you like.

**Assigning (almost) all the space to the root partition**

```
lvexpand /dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_root -L +202G
```

(You can do it more precisely by using "extents" - An extent is a chunk of data in an LVM - the size of a chunk will differ depending on how LVM was set up - you could use vgdisplay to see the available extents, and replace -L +202G with -l +number_of_extents.)

Then you grow the root drive online.

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_root
```

(Note that some distros use resize2fs, others use resize4fs - both commands to the same and operate on standard ext4 filesystems).

Other thoughts:  It is often beneficial to not use all the available space in the logical volume - If you have free space, LVM can allow you to take snapshots, which can help with backing up a busy system without downtime or inconsistency, and if you need to assign space later, you can always add it then.   IT IS ALSO A LOT EASIER TO GROW A PARTITION THEN IT IS TO SHRINK IT - Shrinking a filesystem can only be done offline.  I'd recommend you leave aside at least 30 gigs, ie only expand the LVM to 170 gigs, no the full 203.   You can always expand it more later (using the same commands)

Comment: Without disputing anything you say, in this partition the 50G for / will also include all the space for logs and a lot of "system" data like the default location for postgres and myql databases and the like.

Comment: There is indeed logic to placing /var on another partition if you expect to keep large amounts of log data. I do that on my log server. That said, I generally allocate 20GB for / and use a separate partition for /home, and perhaps add a data partition for databases or multi-user content. 50G actually seems surprisingly large. It seems weird if you are using Windows, as it tries to put almost everything in c:\, but for linux I'd say this diverges from the norm by being larger rather than smaller. They probably expect you to install large application suites.

Comment: BryanK mentioned a "hosting provider." This might mean that the system is being used as a server, in which case a large `/var` or `/srv` might be desirable, perhaps in preference to a large `/home`. It might be reasonable in this case to move the contents of `/home` to the `/` filesystem and tweak it so that a (possibly renamed) `/dev/mapper/vg_d0-lv_home` is mounted at `/var` or `/srv` (after first moving its contents). There are lots of sites on the Internet that describe the purpose of various Linux directories and partitions. Searching on "Linux FHS" may be informative to BryanK.

Comment: I am anxious to test this solution. I may be able to piece together the steps to try it though am not experienced with fstab or the tools necessary and would really appreciate a list of the specifics. 

The reasoning behind this scheme makes sense and the comments here are very helpful. `/var` is exactly where we are using up space with logs and mysql.

Comment: Ok, I've modified my answer with the solution to this.

Comment: It is a good idea to have `/home` (and other, non-distribution) data separate, as it simplifies updating. An install from scratch can be told to leave separate "partitions" alone, and just reformat `/` if need be.